# Center jquery tabbed panel on screen

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery, struts

I have a tabbedpanel declared like so :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
    <sj:tabbedpanel id="mytabs2" selectedTab="0">
      <sj:tab id="tab1" href="one.jsp" label="Tagged"/>
      <sj:tab id="tab2" href="two.jsp" label="Search"/>
      <sj:tab id="tab3" href="three.jsp" label="Add"/>
    </sj:tabbedpanel>
```

I'm using the struts2 jquery plugin - http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/

How can I resize and center the tab on screen ?
The tab should be 70% in width and appear in the center.

I've tried wrapping the tabbedpanel in a dev element and then using :

```
  <style>
  div { width:80%; text-align:center;  }
  </style>
```

But its not working too well. The width resizes but messes up my formatting within the tab elements. Is there another way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Centering a div can be done by setting it's width to the desired value and setting margin to auto. Text-align only affects inline elements inside the div. (This is why your design gets messed up.)

```
div.yours { width: 70%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto }
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Where you say div.yours . 'yours' is the div id right ?

Comment: .something defines a class. "div.alma" refers to all divs that are alma class. To select items by id, use # like this: div#loginbox

Comment: Thanks for your help, it seems to be centering it correctly on firefox. But on IE8 it's aligned to the left, is this a browser issue ?

Comment: Adding this worked - <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

Comment: Ok, I just noticed that the contents of my form tab are now all left aligned so the textbox in the form is appearing directly below the label, before they were aligned. here is my code - <s:div id="update"> Do I need to amend this page also ?

 <s:form action="add" theme="css_xhtml">

  <s:textfield cssStyle="mediumfont" name="bean.Name" label="Name" />

 </s:form>

</s:div>

Comment: If no formal DOCTYPE provided, IE8 works in "quirks mode", that is more of an old-ie-way than closer-to-standards way. This is why that happens.

Comment: Thanks for you help, this a more a struts question.

Answer (score 0):

```
div { width:80%; margin: 0 auto 0 auto}
```